# Como gerar números aleatórios grandes em C++?

Tags: c++, random

Estou querendo fazer um gerador de números aleatórios de [0,4], inclusive esses, só que o problema é o meu professor indicou que eu usasse 4 milhões para gerar números aleatórios e que valor **ultrapassa `RAND_MAX`** , então são duas perguntas:

1. Como gerar números `double` aleatórios?
2. Como gerar aleatórios com um intervalo maior que `RAND_MAX`?

Código:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    double populacao[10];
    double aptidao[10];
    srand((unsigned) time(NULL));

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        populacao[i]=(((rand()%400000)/4000000.0)*4);
        cout<<populacao[i]<<endl;
        aptidao[i]=populacao[i];
    }
    system("Pause");
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Depende do compilador, provavelmente está usando um ruim. Veja que [esse chega nos 2 bilhões](https://ideone.com/EXXXuf). Claro que todo compilador que gere pelo menos 32767 está dentro do padrão.

Se você não precisar que possa dar todos os inteiros pode fazer uma multiplicação até atingir o valor desejado.

Se estiver usando C++11 pra cima, e deveria, então pode usar a [biblioteca mais moderna do C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    default_random_engine generator;
    uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0, 4000000);
    double populacao[10];
    double aptidao[10];
    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
        populacao[i] = distribution(generator);
        cout << populacao[i] << endl;
        aptidao[i] = populacao[i];
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/YZec3c). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/llyggwkn-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Math/RandMax.cpp).

Fora isto tem que criar fórmulas mais complexas ou até usar um gerador alternativo, o que eu não acho interessante na maioria dos casos.

Comment: Quem gera números aleatórios é a implementação da API padrão em tempo de execução, e não o compilador.

Comment: Mas depende do compilador qual é a API vai usar. Falei no sentido de conjunto., não que seja o compilador que faz isto.

Answer (score 6):

Você tem várias opções para gerar números bem grandes.

Primeiro, pode sortear vários números e unir em um. Mas cuidado para não criar geradores não uniformes e usar como se fossem. Por exemplo, se o `rand()` sorteia de 0 a 32767 (2^15-1), você pode criar o gerador uniforme

```
int rand2(){
    int temp = rand() ; // Sorteia uniformemente número de 0x0000 a 0x7FFF
    temp <<= 15 ;       // Agora é de 0x00000000 a 0x3FFF8000, múltiplo de  0x8000
    temp += rand() ;    // Agora é sorteio uniforme de 0x00000000 a 0x3FFFFFFF
    return temp ;
}
```

para sortear de 0 a 1073741823 (2^30-1) ou também pode usar

```
long long int rand3(){
    long long int temp = rand2() ; // Sorteia uniformemente número de 0x0000 a 0x3FFFFFFF
    temp <<= 15 ;                  // Agora é de 0x00000000 a 0x1FFFFFFF8000, múltiplo de  0x8000
    temp += rand() ;               // Agora é sorteio uniforme de 0x00000000 a 1FFFFFFFFFFF
    return temp ;
}
```

para sortear de 0 a 35184372088831 (2^45-1), também uniformemente. Outra opção é criar o seu próprio gerador congruente linear de números pseudo-aleatórios (mesma metodologia usada pelas bibliotecas) com uma orientação do wikipedia. Assim, poderá fazer um randomizador do jeito que preferir.

https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geradores_congruentes_lineares
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator

O seguinte, por exemplo, acabei de criar para responder sua questão. Não sei se gera com qualidade porque não testei, mas ele de fato gera uniformemente números de 0 a 4294967295 (2^32-1), provavelmente tem mais desempenho em execução que os anteriores e não precisa que chame `srand()` para gerar aleatoriedade (usa por padrão como semente o relógio), mas também não aceita especificação de seed em caso de precisar.

```
# include <time.h>
unsigned int random(){
    static long long unsigned int state = time(0) ;     // Estado inicial (semente)
    state = 0x23A7489B29LL + 0x50FB738205C1LL * state ; // Atualizar estado atual
    return (unsigned int)( state>>32 ) ;                // Gerar a partir do estado
}
```

Se quiser e encontrar um jeito adequado, pode até criar geradores que geram números de tipo `long long unsigned int` que vão de 0 a 18446744073709551615 (2^64-1), mas para isso precisa de algo mais bem trabalhado usando mais de uma variável de estado.

Quanto a geração de números grandes, tem um número absurdamente grande de opções. Quanto a geração de números do tipo `double`, não sei se é isso que você quer saber, mas a forma mais comum de fazer isso é `rand()/(RAND_MAX+1.0)`, que vai sortear uniformemente números de tipo `double` que vão de 0.000 (incluindo-o) a 1.000 (excluindo-o).

Você pode fazer adaptações visando melhor qualidade de sorteio, maior desempenho e propriedades diferentes (como incluir o 1.000 ou excluir o 0.000). Na minha opinião, uma boa forma de sortear `double` é a seguinte, que modifica o código do `random()` criado anteriormente para fazer sorteio uniforme e contínuo entre dois números de tipo `double`.

```
# include <time.h>
double random( double number1 , double number2 ){
    static long long unsigned int state = time(0) ;                             // Estado inicial (semente)
    state = 0x23A7489B29LL + 0x50FB738205C1LL * state ;                         // Atualizar estado atual
    double zeroToOne ;
    *(long long unsigned int*)&zeroToOne = ( state>>12 )+0x3FF0000000000000LL ; // Gerando número de 0.0 a 1.999999999999999778
    zeroToOne -= 0.999999999999999889 ;                                         // Agora é de 0.000000000000000111  a 0.999999999999999889
    return number1*( 1.0-zeroToOne )+( zeroToOne )*number2 ;                    // Retorna um número aleatório que vai de number1 a number2
}
```

Segundo testes que fiz anos atrás, tem melhor desempenho do que fazendo a divisão com typecast implícito. É matematicamente bom porque tem alta granularidade, assim retratando bem a propriedade de continuidade do sorteio.

Alguma dúvida?

Answer (score 2):

A função `rand()` é capaz de retornar números inteiros na faixa entre `0` e `RAND_MAX`.

É garantido pelo padrão que `RAND_MAX` nunca tenha um valor inferior a `32.767`, o que faz com que `rand()` sempre retorne um número aleatório de, no mínimo, `15 bits`.

O padrão `C99` garante que o tipo `unsigned long long` tenha no mínimo `64 bits`, ou seja, faixa entre `0` e `18.446.744.073.709.551.615`.

Partindo dessas premissas, se cada chamada da função `rand()` é capaz de me retornar `15 bits` aleatórios, com 5 chamadas eu sou capaz de acumular `75 bits`.

Com o devido processamento lógico, é possível "montar" um número aleatório de `64 bits`, com um implementação portável `C99`, vejamos:

```
unsigned long long llrand( void )
{
    unsigned long long ret = 0;

    for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
    {
        ret = (ret << 15) | (rand() & 0x7FFF);
    }

    return( ret & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFULL );
}
```

Código de teste:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>


unsigned long long llrand( void )
{
    unsigned long long ret = 0;

    for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
    {
        ret = (ret << 15) | (std::rand() & 0x7FFF);
    }

    return( ret & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFULL );
}


int main( void )
{
    std::srand(std::time(NULL));

    for( int i = 0; i < 20; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << llrand() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Saída:

```
$ ./rand64 
8105869587383598689
6277277725189066831
1509360212795395722
1130692503851307412
14335258242796316152
5075740159224506903
14680498390136040740
7165466167364905026
16797692089103744121
16486198844466236119
7276392683204141714
8357279606092084573
16367915918020953270
16380497907074646611
16976708914435940256
10292415635872591979
13954955472883015315
6877101750998155002
11106815715087335245
5831095514054045134
```

Comment: Apenas uma nota que me lembrei: o gerador de números aleatórios da biblioteca padrão do seu compilador pode ter uma entropia distinta entre bits altos e baixos. Se, por acaso, a entropia dos primeiros 7 bits for baixa, porém a dos outros 8 bits for alta, você pode perceber que o número resultante dessa operação não seja tão aleatório quanto você espera. Por entropia baixa entenda que o padrão se repete, que há pouca alteração entre um número aleatório e o seu consecutivo

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado: Bem observado. A entropia das séries de números aleatórios gerados através dessa técnica é baixíssima e talvez não seja adequada para determinadas aplicações.